# How can we check that if an array has retain count=0 or not?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

How can we check that if an array was in memory or not?

I have a condition where i need it

is following code is correct to release an array

```
if (array1)
{
[array1 release];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Prob should nil it out too, that way you can guarantee that if that code is run again array1 will be false and it wont get over released.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to send release to nil.  You never need to check if an object is nil before releasing it.  @Rudiger's advice is good though.  It'll stop you sending release to an already deallocated object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking the retain count of objects on Obj-C. At best that number is barely useful for debugging and at worst it is grossly misleading. If you practice proper memory management techniques, you will never need to check the retain count.

If you're having trouble with memory management, post more code and we can help you track down where your problem lies. Also, if you havent read this, you should.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you need to know more about array1 other than its `retainCount` and whether it is `nil`.  If you are pointing to an object that was released elsewhere, calling `retainCount` can either crash your program or return complete garbage.

---

[Removed my comment about autorelease - it was misinformed. The above remains true still!]

Comment: There is no garbage collector with retain/release.   The order and time with which an object is released and deallocated is quite determinant.

Comment: Sorry, re-read up on autorelease pools and removed the bit about autorelease.  Still adjusting from C# land! URL for the curious:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score -3):

If condition is correct. using that you can check whether array is in memory or not. After releasing the array you should assign nil as well. So it will remove entirely from the memory.

Cheers,
Raxit

Comment: Assigning `nil` does not "remove entirely from memory".